# rclone not replacing invalid characters when syncing to SD card

Tags: linux, sync, sd-card, filenames, rclone

I'm using `rclone` to sync stuff to both Google Drive and my phone's SD card formatted as `vFAT`. I've created the test file named `a*b?c:` containing special characters that are in my music library. Copying that file to Drive works just fine but I can't seem to sync the same way to the SD card.

```sh
$ sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 mnt
$ sudo rclone copy -P 'a*b?c:' mnt/
2022/01/26 09:13:47 Failed to create file system for "a*b?c:": config name contains invalid characters - may only contain `0-9`, `A-Z`, `a-z`, `_`, `-` and space
```

My version info:

```sh
$ rclone --version
rclone v1.57.0
- os/version: arch (64 bit)
- os/kernel: 5.16.2-arch1-1 (x86_64)
- os/type: linux
- os/arch: amd64
- go/version: go1.17.5
- go/linking: dynamic
- go/tags: none
```

How can I get `rclone` to sync files whose names contain special characters to my SD card?